# Phonegap how to auto show keyboard

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova

I have a phonegap application using Angular. The problem I'm having is that I want to allow user to enter their email in a form inside a modal.

```
$scope.email = function () {

    $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/modals/sales/email.html',
        size: "md",
        windowClass: 'center-modal',
        controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

            //$("#email").focus();

            $scope.submit = function () {

            };

            $scope.close = function () {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            }
        }
    });

};
```

Now the template for that modal is this.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <form name="form" ng-submit="submit(form)" novalidate>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 class="text-center">Please enter your email</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <input type="email" class="form-control btn-block input-lg" ng-model="customer.email" id="email" autofocus>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-6">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg" type="button" ng-click="close()">Close</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" type="submit" ng-click="submit()">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The problem that as you can see the input type email need to be focus when the modals open up, but instead my input is getting focus but the virtual keyboard on iOS is not showing up until I manually tap on the input.

How can I show up the virtual keyboard when the modal opens up.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

install the below cordova plugin

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard

call `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show()`